# In loop, find if two records belong to same post

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a loop of questions where each question belongs to a post and the post title is displayed above the question. If 2 ( or 3 or 4 etc) questions in a row belong to the same post I only want to display the post name once. My idea was to use an index to check if the prior questions post == the current questions post. The problem is I'm not sure how that would work.

Here is what I tried:

```
<% @questions.each_with_index do |question, i| %>

<% unless (i-1).comment.post == question.comment.post %>
 <%= question.comment.post.title %>
<% end %>

<% end %>
```

This gives me an undefined method comment error since I can't call '(i-1).comment' but can I do something like that or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: How can you say `(i-1).comment.post`? i seems to a be a Fixnum here. Are you sure code you've posted is correct?

Comment: Yep sorry, the error: 'undefined method `comment' for -1:Fixnum'.

Comment: Where is `comment.post` coming from? Can you post whole view code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this would be to use `group_by` to group the questions by post:

```
<% @questions.group_by {|q| q.comment.post}.each do |post, questions| %>
  <%= post.title %>

  <% for question in questions %>
    <%= question.title %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Hey, something like group_by is exactly what I want! One problem though: 'post.title' gives me a nil:NilClass error. Any clue why?

Comment: Is it possible that one of the questions does not have an associated post?

Comment: Haha oops, yes you're right. So that seems to work perfectly. One question: does this only group them if they are consecutive or does it group all of the questions with the same post. If the latter, how does it order the grouped posts?

Comment: What I want (and I think this does it) is to take the first questions post and group all the questions with that post and then move on to the next question with a different post and do the same thing.

Comment: Each iteration gives you a single post and all of it's questions. Is that what you're asking?

Answer (score 1):

If you need to maintain the order of the questions, you could use [`each_cons`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_cons).

```
<%= @questions.first.comment.post.title %>

<% @questions.each_cons(2) do |previous_question, question| %>
  <% unless previous_question.comment.post == question.comment.post %>
   <%= question.comment.post.title %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Couple of minor notes:

1. This is a troubling Law of Demeter violation (having to traverse from the question to the comment to the post and eventually the title).
2. This sort of complicated data manipulation is much better in a Ruby object than in a template. Ideally, templates are dead simple.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This works and does what my question asked but I think @infused 'group_by' suggestion fits my needs better. Thanks for the help though.